# With the jquery version older than 3.2.1, messages pop up not under the form field, but in the upper left corner of the screen. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a form, if you enter an error in the field below this field, an error or informational message pops up.

**Used by:**
**jquery** and **notify**

All this works correctly **up to version 3.2.1 of jquery inclusive**.

With the latest 2 versions of **jquery - 3.3.1 and 3.4.0**, messages pop up not under the form field, but in the upper left corner of the screen.

**Help me fix it!**

**But the working form with jquery is 3.2.1. Commented out the connection to the latest versions of jquery.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Базовый шаблон</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">

<style>
body {
  background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

form {
  display:block;
  width:450px;
  height:auto;
  margin:50px auto;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:15px;
  background-color:rgb(84, 84, 84);
  font-size:16px;
  font-family:'Arial';
  color:rgb(255, 255, 255)
}

table {
  margin:0 auto;
}

table td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

table td.lbl {
  padding-top:12px;
}

#title {
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  color:rgb(0, 184, 246);
}

.textbox {
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  margin-left:10px;
  padding:10px;
  border:none;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-color:rgb(190, 190, 190);
  font-size:16px;
  color:rgb(63, 63, 63);
}

.errtextbox {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(255,0,0);
}

.help {
  width:190px;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:25px;
  padding-left:25px;
  font-size:12px;
  color:rgb(140, 140, 140);
}

#info {
  height:100px;
  resize:none;
}

#send {
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto 10px;
  padding:7px;
  border:none;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:rgb(0, 128, 174);
  font-size:16px;
  color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
</style>    
</head>
<body>

  <form action="/reg" method="POST" id="regForm">
  <lable id="title">Запрос на регистрацию</lable>
  <table>
    <tboby>
      <tr>
        <td class="lbl">Имя:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="textbox"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><lable class="help">От 2 до 25 символов</lable></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="lbl">E-mail:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" class="textbox"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><lable class="help">только @mail.com</lable></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="lbl">Пароль:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" class="textbox"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><lable class="help">от 5 до 10 символов</lable></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="lbl">Полтвердить:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" class="textbox"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><lable class="help">должен совпадать с паролем</lable></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="lbl">Информация:</td>
        <td><textarea maxlength="250" name="info" id="info" class="textbox"></textarea>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><lable class="help">в свободной форме, максисум 250 символов</lable></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="button" id="send" value="Отправить заявку"/>
</form>

<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/notifyjs/notifyjs/master/dist/notify.js"></script>

<script>
/* Изначально форма не заполнена и по этому считаем что все возможные ошибки есть  */
/* Initially, the form is not filled out and therefore we believe that all possible errors are */
var errorNull = true, errorMail = true, errorPass = true;

/* Для удобства и уменьшения размера кода выносим функцию проверки поля на null в отдельную переменную */
/* For convenience and reduce the size of the code, we move the field check function to null into a separate variable */
var checkNull = function(){
  $(this).val($(this).val().trim());
  if ($(this).val() =="") {
    /* Выводим сообщение об ошибке под элементом.
       This в данном случае это элемент, который инициировал вызов функции */
    /* Display an error message under the item.
        "this" in this case is the element that initiated the function call */     
    $(this).notify("Поле нужно заполнить", "error"); 
    $(this).addClass("errtextbox");
    errorNull = true;
  } else {
    errorNull = false;
    $(this).removeClass("errtextbox");
  }
};

/* Проверяем значения полей Имя и Информация на null в момент когда они теряют фокус */
/* Check the values of the Name and Information fields to null when they lose focus */
$("#name").focusout(checkNull);
$("#info").focusout(checkNull);

/* Проверка поля Имя на соответствие длинны */
/* Checking the Name field for matching length */
$("#name").keyup(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value.length > 24 || value.length < 2){ 
    $(this).notify("От 2 до 25 символов", "info");
    $(this).val(value.slice(0,24));
  }
});

/* Проверяем корректность E-mail */
/* Check the correctness of the E-mail */
$("#mail").focusout(function(){
  var value = $(this).val().trim();
/* Для этого используем регулярное выражение  */
/* For this we use a regular expression */
  if (value.search(/^[a-z0-9]{3,}@mail\.com$/i) != 0) {
    $(this).notify("E-mail введён не корректно", "error");
    $(this).addClass("errtextbox");
    errorMail = true;
  } else { 
    $(this).removeClass("errtextbox");
    errorMail = false;
  }
});

/* Проверяем длину пароля */
/* Check the password length */
$("#password1").focusout(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value.length <= 4) { 
    $(this).notify("Минимум 5 символов", "error");
    $(this).addClass("errtextbox");
    errorPass = true;
  } else {
    if (value.length > 9) {
      $(this).notify("Миксимум 10 символов", "error");
      $(this).addClass("errtextbox");
      errorPass = true;
    } else {
      errorPass = false;
      $(this).removeClass("errtextbox");
    }
  }
});

/* Проверяем соответствие пароля и подтверждения */
/* We check the compliance of the password and confirmation */
$("#password2").focusout(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value != $("#password1").val()) {
    $(this).notify("Пароль не совпадает", "error");
    $(this).addClass("errtextbox");
    errorPass = true;
  } else {
    errorPass = false;
    $(this).removeClass("errtextbox");     
  }
});

/* В результате клика по кнопке отправить если ошибок заполнения нет то форма отправляется иначе получаем сообщение об ошибке */
/* As a result of clicking on the send button, if there are no errors, then the form is sent, otherwise we get an error message */
$("#send").click(function(){
  if (!(errorNull || errorMail || errorPass)) {
    $("#regForm").submit();
  } else {
    $(this).notify("Форма пустая или заполнена не корректно", "error");
  }
});
</script>  



</body>
</html>
```